# Flutter - Listening for data changes in user profile (Firestore) of Firebase user using provider package

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-provider

By now I successfully react on auth-changes of my Firebase user to map it to my own custom user class

```dart
import 'package:mypckg/models/user.dart' as local;
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
import 'package:mypckg/services/database.dart';

class AuthService {
  final auth.FirebaseAuth _auth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on firebase user
  Future<local.User> _userFromFirebaseUser(auth.User user) async {
    return user != null
        ? local.User(/* ... init user properties ... */)
        : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<local.User> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().asyncMap(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

...
```

In Cloud Firestore I store additional values of that user which are not covered by Firebase user e.g.

[image: users collection in Cloud Firestore]

In **main.dart** the provider is set to provide my app with the local user in case he signed in or signed out (authStateChanges). My idea was to subscribe to another stream which will listen to changes on the 'users' document in Cloud Firestore.

```dart
class MyPckg extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final i18n = I18n.delegate;
    //AuthService().signInAnon();
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<User>(
          create: (_) => AuthService().user,
        ),
        /* my idea to subscribe to another stream which will listen to changes on user details in Firestore */
        StreamProvider<User>(
          create: (_) => AuthService().customUser,
        ),
      ],
      child: DynamicTheme(
        defaultBrightness: Brightness.light,
        data: (brightness) {

...
```

I have a profile view where the user may edit those values, e.g. the locale and it gets written to the Firestore correctly with

```dart
Future<void> updateUserLanguage(String language) async {
    return await usersCollection.doc(uid).update({
      'language': language,
    });
  }
```

But the view is not rebuild as the current stream only reacts to authStateChanges.

Does anyone have a working example how to setup the link from users in Firestore collection that my app will listen to changes done there? What will my customUser method have to look like?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you stuck? More specifically, what error are you facing?

Comment: Well, I am not sure about how to design the structure in general. Do I have to work with FutureBuilder in my view which displays and changes the custom user values or should a simple initialization of the user object from provider be sufficient? like

```dart
final User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
```

Comment: i have the exact question. did you ever figure out a solution? @Ocrimops

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: I'm working on the same issue right now, https://medium.com/flutter-community/firebase-startup-logic-and-custom-user-profiles-6309562ea8b7 seems to get close to what we're trying to achieve. Will post an answer when I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I've decided to wrap everything in my logged-in state with a StreamProvider:

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return StreamProvider<Profile>.value(
        value: DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).profile,
        initialData: Profile(userName: '0', userRole: '0'),
        child: HomeScreen(),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The db service takes in the UID and returns a snapshot:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({
    this.uid,
  });

static CollectionReference _profileCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('profiles');

  Stream<Profile> get profile {
    return _profileCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_profileFromSnapshot);
  }

  Profile _profileFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    return Profile(
      userName: snapshot.data()['userName'] ?? '',
      userRole: snapshot.data()['role'] ?? '',
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, I use the data via a Consumer wherever I need it:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Consumer<Profile>(builder: (
            context,
            profile,
            child,
          ) {
            return Text(profile.userName)
...
```

edit: I've made a video about this technique. Link: https://youtu.be/mAH9YT_y6ec

Comment: Hey, could you post a link to your code if it's open-source? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, it's a private repo, which part are you not understanding?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I am doing exactly the same as you are. But my stream is still not being updated when a new user signs in & still shows old data from the logged out user. Here's my  code [link](https://github.com/arpit-d/hospital-app/tree/main/lib) for reference. Thanks.

Comment: If I ever get the mental cycles, I'll put out a video series on this.  It seems to be a common issue.  Plus Nav2.0, but that's another story.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are struggling with this approach as well, here is my solution (thanks to all contributors who lead me to that approach):

I set up a method "setAppUser" in MyClass which can be called from any child. Important for this

```
static _MyClassState? of(BuildContext context) =>
          context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyClassState>();
```

So here is main.dart (only the necessary sections):

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
  static _MyClassState? of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyClassState>();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  User appUser = User();

  set setAppUser(User user) => {
        setState(() {
          appUser = user;
        })
      };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          StreamProvider<UserLogin>(
            initialData: UserLogin(signedIn: false),
            create: (_) => AuthService().userAuthStateChanges,
            catchError: (_, error) => UserLogin(signedIn: false),
          ),
          StreamProvider<User>(
            initialData: appUser,
            create: (_) => AuthService().userData,
            catchError: (_, error) => appUser,
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
        ...
```

In my sign-in form I call the "setAppUser" method of my main.dart after receiving a new user of my sign-in. Now the widget gets rebuilt and the new appUser is set to my provider.

```
  ...
  await _auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    textControllerEmail.text,
    textControllerPassword.text)
      .then((result) {
        if (result.id != "") {
          MyClass.of(context)!.setAppUser = result;
          ...
```